# Can't build JAssimp.dll for Windows x86

Tags: java, linker, unresolved-external, assimp

So, I'm trying to get into LWJGL, and part of this is loading 3D models, and I thought I'd use JAssimp for this. The readme specifies two steps, building a native component, and a .jar component. The jar was just an ant build, and so it happened without incident. The part that's difficult is the native library. I've been trying to link it, without success. I've included the assimp include directories, included Java's headers, and linked to JAssimp's assimp.lib. However, I still get these errors:

```
jassimp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _aiImportFile referenced in function _Java_jassimp_Jassimp_aiImportFile@20
jassimp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _aiReleaseImport referenced in function _Java_jassimp_Jassimp_aiImportFile@20
jassimp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _aiGetErrorString referenced in function _Java_jassimp_Jassimp_aiImportFile@20
C:\Users\Kevin\Downloads\assimp-3.1.1-win-binaries\port\jassimp\jassimp-native\src\Release\Jassimp.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
```

Googling around leads to mostly the same question, but with no answers, and one guy on facepunch that apparently found a solution, but pulled an https://xkcd.com/979/ and never mentioned how. Obviously, I've missed linking to some library, but I'm not sure what else to link to, Assimp only provided me one, and I'm not sure what else I need. Am I installing it wrong?

Comment: There is a very incomplete pure port of Assimp called jAssimp too (available on Github) and there are numerous more maintained Java libraries to load models but they use a full blown 3D engine which is logical as you need some math tools to implement this kind of feature.

Comment: I've looked at that library, but it only supports one, rather old format.

Comment: The pure Java equivalent of jAssimp only supports MD2 as far as I know but there are numerous 3D engines (JMonkeyEngine, JogAmp's Ardor3D Continuation, Xith3D, 3DzzD, Unlicense-lib, ...) and frameworks (LibGDX, ...) including several importers and exporters for the following formats: WaveFront OBJ, PLY, STL, ASE, 3DS, DAE (Collada), WRL (VRML), X3D, Blender, FBX, LWO, Maya, X, MS3D, BVH, ...

Comment: You can use this library to import Blender models: http://www.java-gaming.org/topics/java-blend-blender-dna-fully-implemented-in-java-with-r-w-file-access-beta/36939/view.html

Comment: Looks interesting, but I've realized that making the import part of my main engine is probably a bad idea, and I've moved to a little C# app that just uses Assimp.net to read in the data, and just dumps the vertex data and indexes to a binary file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who stumbles across this with the same problem, the answer is to do it the old-fashioned way and compile the C++ Assimp yourself. This will give you, (among other things) a new assimp.lib. Link with this instead of the one provided, and the error will go away.

Answer (score 0):

### How To Build

I)  buiid the primary shared object libassimp.so: issue these commands in AssImp/assimp-3.2
    a. cmake CMakeLists.txt -G 'Unix Makefiles'
    b. make
    c. results in AssImp/assimp-3.2/lib

II) build the native library by issuing this command in jassimp-native/src:
    a. $ gcc jassimp.cpp -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include/ \
                         -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include/linux \
                         -I/$HOME/AssImp/assimp-3.2/include \
                         -L/$HOME/AssImp/assimp-3.2/lib/libassimp.so -shared -fPIC -o libjassimp.so

```
libjassimp.so is required at runtime and must be located in java.library.path:
b. sudo cp /$HOME/AssImp/assimp-3.2/port/jassimp/jassimp-native/src/libjassimp.so   /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/
```

III) Java binding
    The java library is built using ant. Executing "ant" in the port/jassimp
    directory should be sufficient to build the library including the docs.
    The java build is configured to create java 1.6 classes

```
The Jassimp.jar file generated by the "ant" call has to be incorporated
in your build.xml file:

<target name="init">
   <property name="imports"      value="${libs}/jogl-all.jar:${libs}/gluegen-rt.jar:${libs}/jassimp.jar" />

<target name="compile" depends="prepare">
   <compilerarg line="-Xlint -cp ${imports}" />
```

All of the above is the good news; I successfully built my code.

The bad news is that upon execution I received the following error:
java: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjassimp.so: undefined symbol: aiImportFile

Comment: I'm a little confused here. Are you asking for help, or are you quoting someone?

Comment: My apologies, I didn't mean to add to the confusion.

The original question was how to compile the JassImp library.  
I provided an approach that worked in my Ubuntu 14.04 environment.

Within my code I called the method Jassimp.importFile ("cube.ply").
This method, in turn, called the aiImportFile () function.  
Unfortunately the library could not find aiImportFile ().  So, at
this point I don't know if I made a mistake or if the library has 
an error.  

Right now I'm looking for alternatives for Jassimp.

Comment: I ended up using Assimp for C# and just pouring all the data I needed in binary to a file format I made up, and just parsing that in Java.

Comment: Yeah, I did the same thing except I stuck with java and used an ascii file, not binary.
This prohibits me from using defined formats but I can get on with writing my code.